# Can we remove the time and date info from the tooltip generated on hover over the event in fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, tooltip

[image]

here I want to remove the time and date info from the tooltip, how can we do that?

The tooltip comes in on hover over the fullcalendar on the events on a perticular day. so i just want to display the information of the event not the time and date info along with it .

below is the code -

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.calendarTitle = this.calendarInfo.Name;  
    this.calendarTitleJql = this.calendarInfo.jql;
    // if (this.calendarData[0]) {
    //   this.eventField = Object.keys(this.calendarData[0])[6];
    // }

    this.eventsInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.calendarData).split(this.eventField).join('eventDate'));

    this.events = this.eventsInfo.map(function (_ref) {
      var Status = _ref.Status,
        eventDate = _ref.eventDate,
        Created = _ref.Created,
       Key = _ref.Key;
      return { title: Status, start: eventDate, id: Key };
    });


  }

  isloading(e) {
    console.log('loading');
  }

  handleEventClick(e) {
    this.userService.showTicket(e.calEvent.id);
  }

  calendarTitleClick() {
    this.userService.search(this.calendarTitleJql);
  }

  loadEvents(e) {

    if (this) {
      let month = e.view.start._d.getMonth() + 2;
      let year = e.view.start._d.getFullYear();

      if (month == '13') {
        month = 1;
        year = year + 1;
      }





        });

        this.events = this.eventsData;
      });
    }
  }

  onEventMouseover({calEvent:data,jsEvent:event,view}){
    const el = event.currentTarget;
    var coord = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(this.timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId)
    }

    this.hoveredEventData = { 
      event: data,
      position: {
        top: coord.top - 80 ,
        left: coord.left + el.offsetWidth - 350 
      },
    };
  }

  onEventMouseout({ calEvent: data, jsEvent: event, view }) {
    {
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => this.hoveredEventData = null, 3000);
    } 
  }
```

html -

```
<div class="gadget-body">
   <p-schedule [events]="events" 

   </p-schedule>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="hoveredEventData" class="event-tooltip"
  [style.top.px]="hoveredEventData.position.top"
  [style.left.px]="hoveredEventData.position.left">
  {{ hoveredEventData.event.title }}
  {{ hoveredEventData.event.start }}
</div>
```

so here i am confused where to edit code so in tooltip the time should not show up and also in tooltip the wwc-414 key should be in bold , how can i do that.

Comment: This isn't a native feature of fullCalendar, so presumably you have written some code to do it. All you need to do is change that code so it doesn't include the time and date. If you're not sure what you need to do, please show your code for creating the tooltip and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @ADysonv  ok thanks for the help, i will share the code and i also want the key i.e. wwc-414 to be in bold in tooltip

Comment: I guess you would just remove `{{ hoveredEventData.event.start }}` from the last bit. That seems to be the part describing the event date. For the bold part I'm not really sure, I don't know angular and how you would define a style on that specific bit of text.

Comment: @ADyson - that is correct, now it does not show up in tooltip. one more thing how can i make the wwc- 417 as bold in tooltip ?

Comment: read my comment above again, I already explained I'm not really sure,

Comment: @ADyson - thats fine. thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `{{ hoveredEventData.event.start }}` from the `<div *ngIf="hoveredEventData"` section and the date will no longer be shown in the tooltip.